# unmet dependencies for libxml2

Tags: gdal, lidar

Trying to install libgdal-dev.  The purpose is for use with liblas.  Here is my attempt.

1. sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev ----> libgdal-dev : Depends: libdap-dev but it is not going to be installed
2. sudo apt-get install libdap-dev -----> libdap-dev : Depends: libxml2-dev but it is not going to be installed
3. sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev ----> libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.8.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu2.1) but 2.8.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu2.2~precise1 is to be installed

Can't locate anything in synaptic relevant to the solution.  seems like i might need to sudo udpate && sudo upgrade, which hasn't changed anything.

What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this issue after upgrading from Ubuntu precise (12.04) to quantal (12.10). I believe something went wrong during the upgrade of libxml2, and the old version remained.

The way you can solve it is by downloading a newer build of libxml2 from the [Quantal's lauchpad repositoring](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/libxml2/2.8.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu2.1) and installing it manually. Choose a build for your system, and install using:

```
sudo dpkg -i libxml2_2.8.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

I couldn't solve it using apt-get/aptitude, as they seemed to detected the precise version as the latest.